# Eigenvalues of sums of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've been thinking about this problem for awhile now and making no progress. I'm curious if anyone has any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Let $A$ be the $n \times n$ matrix where $a_{11} = 1$ and all other components are $0$. Does there exist an $n \times n$ complex matrix $B$ such that $B$ and $A+B$ share no common eigenvalues?

I know for the $2 \times 2$ case there exists such a $B$:

$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 
2 & 2 \\
2 & 2 
\end{pmatrix} $$

It's straightforward to check that the eigenvalues of $B$ don't share an overlap with the eigenvalues of $A+B$. However, for the $3 \times 3$ case, I don't really know where to begin, let alone for the $n \times n$ case.

Comment: Characteristic polynomials roots shouldnt match implies graphs will never intersect when can such things happen ? (Take cases with different degrees)

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Just because the roots of the characteristic polynomials don't match doesn't mean the graphs won't intersect. Just take the polynomials $x^2 - 1$ and $2x^2 - 1$.

Comment: No not like that they wont intersect at roots of two polynomials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, take for instance for $B$ the permutation matrix for the cycle $(n~1~2~\cdots~n-1)$:
$$B=\pmatrix{0&1&0&\ldots&0\\0&0&1&\ldots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\ddots&1\\1&0&0&\ddots&0}.
$$
Then $B$ is similar to the companion matrix of the polynomial $X^n-1$, which is therefore its characteristic polynomial, and whose roots are the $n$-th roots of unity. Also $A+B$ is similar to the companion matrix of $X^n-X^{n-1}-1$, of which none of the $n$-th roots of unity are roots. By the same argument we could put anything in the first column of $B$, as long as the final entry is nonzero (so that $0$ is not an eigenvalue).

Comment: Clever! Thanks!